# Calculate Rank Pattern without any order value

Tags: sql

My Data is like this -

[image]

You can check 3 columns, **jil_equipment_id,req_group,operand.** 
Based on these 3 columns i have to generate a new "**Patern**" Column.

The patern column is a patern and starts from 2 and increases by 1 for each repeated combination of **jil_equipment_id,req_group,operand.**

The final data will look like this. 
[image]

Please suggest me any possible approach. I am not able to use the RANK()/DENSE_RANK() Function on this.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please add the tag for the database you are using.  Also, explain why you cannot use the ranking functions.

Comment: i am using SQL Server

Comment: Can't use Rank functions coz, they work on ASC/DESC Values, My pattern is based on 3 different columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`.  You want to use the `partition by` as well:

```
select t.*,
       (1 + row_number() over (partition by jil_equipment_id, req_group, operand
                               order by content_id
                              )
       ) as pattern
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked.

PS - How stupid i am not to now see content_id column

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,Row_Number() over(partition by jil_equipment_id,req_group,operand   order by  jil_equipment_id,req_group,operand) + 1 as pattern
from tab
```

you can use `row_number()` function for this.

Comment: Dosn't work. jil_equipment_id,req_group,operand are not in any ASC/DESC order. It is like for each jil_equipment_id, we have to check each req_group for multiple operands and create pattern accordingly.
If there are more than 2 operands for each jil_equipment_id,req_group it should increase by 1 or else it remains 2

Comment: use partition by as well